# Do two symmetric matrix of the same size commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If i have two symmetric matrix A and B of the same size, do A and B commute?
If not, what is a counter example?

This is related to a problem in my intro to linear alg class.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about this yourself?  Did you try a simple example of this and see what happens ... and how that might lead to either a general proof or a counterexample?

Comment: This question arises from the true or false question: "If A and B are symmetric, then AB must also be symmetric."

Comment: Write out the multiplication. See what happens.

Comment: I've tried 2 by 2 and 3 by 3, they all seems to be commutative for all size.

Comment: But according to here: http://web.mst.edu/~insall/courses/linalg1/Solved%20Problems/Matrix%20Products/Problem_2.pdf .It seems that it's not always true.

Comment: Try harder to find 2x2 counterexample.

Comment: @DavidCheng Did you try $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$?

Comment: Try $2\times2$ matrices with three distinct entries, i.e., different entries on the diagonal.

Comment: try $\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\2&1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 5&1\\1&6\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 25, accepted):

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 4):

If $ A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
b & c\\
\end{array} \right) $

and $ B = 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
y & z\\
\end{array} \right) $

then $AB = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
ax+by & ay+bz \\
bx+cy & by+cz\\
\end{array} \right) $

so $BA = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
ax + by & bx + cy\\
ay + bz & by + cz\\
\end{array} \right)$.

So, as an example, try taking $A$ with $b=c=0$.

Comment: This actually make sense, since $AB = A^TB^T = (BA)^T$ by definition of symmetric matrices